# Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx). error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, collections

I need to save those six fields in same column but not in same row and same cell. each field have default GUID.so i decided to put that default guid's in one list and fields in one list and call that object of that particular list where we want .

```
       ArrayList Alist = new ArrayList();
        {
            Alist.Add("FD713788-B5AE-49FF-8B2C-F311B9CB0CC4");
            Alist.Add("64B512E7-46AE-4989-A049-A446118099C4");
            Alist.Add("376D45C8-659D-4ACE-B249-CFBF4F231915");
            Alist.Add("59A2449A-C5C6-45B5-AA00-F535D83AD48B");
            Alist.Add("03ADA903-D09A-4F53-8B67-7347A08EDAB1");
            Alist.Add("2F405521-06A0-427C-B9A3-56B8931CFC57");
        }

        ArrayList objValue = new ArrayList();
        {
            objValue.Add(viewmodel.TinNo);
            objValue.Add(viewmodel.CstNo);
            objValue.Add(viewmodel.PanNo);
            objValue.Add(viewmodel.CinNo);
            objValue.Add(viewmodel.ExciseRegNo);
            objValue.Add(viewmodel.ServiceTaxNo);
        }

   var TaxInfoTaxFiledclassobj = new TaxInfoTaxFiled()
        {

            TaxInfoTaxFieldID = TaxInfoTaxFieldObj,
            TaxFieldID = new Guid(Alist .ToString ()),
            FieldValue = objValue.ToString(),
        };
```

All are working Fine 
but in TaxFieldID  it show the count which has been calculated from list  but while saving it show the below error

[image]

What shall I do?

Comment: **DON"T** add images of the code, they're not useful. **Add Actual code**

Comment: Post your code and error in text format

Comment: ok wait  i add my code

Comment: For me, this error comes only when I _debug_ the application in Visual Studio. If I launch the output EXE _directly_ from the Debug folder, then this error never comes. It seems this issue has something to do with the VS Debugger as well.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to pass an `ArrayList` as a Guid. In this line:

```
TaxFieldID = Guid.Parse(Alist.ToString())
```

You need to select just one of the elements of the `ArrayList` to parse. Additionally, you could use a `List<Guid>` to eliminate the problem altogether.

```
List<Guid> guidList = new List<Guid>();
guidList.Add(new Guid("DDE4BA55-808E-479F-BE8B-72F69913442F"));

...

TaxFieldID = guidList[0]; // obviously, select the appropriate GUID
```

Comment: steve  please tell i add my default guid as per you said and how to add my six fields same as like this as per you said

Comment: I've just put the pertinent parts for the answer, the rest of the code will be the same as you had. This just deals with setting the Guid value.

Comment: but i need to save those 6 guid in same column by row by row that's my requiremnet

Comment: Do you mean a row for each Guid, or all Guids in one column in one row, perhaps separated by a comma or something?

Comment: Yes  i need  to save  each guid  in row by row of same Column    in the below format                    [enter image description here][1]     [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/42dkd.png

Answer (score 2):

`Guid.Parse()` is capable of parsing a GUID. `Alist.ToString()` should not be a GUID.

**EDIT**

I guess you're looking for something like this -

```
var listFiled = new List<TaxInfoTaxFiled>();
for(var item = 0; item < objValue.Count ; item++)
{
    listFiled.Add(new TaxInfoTaxFiled
    {

        TaxInfoTaxFieldID = TaxInfoTaxFieldObj,
        TaxFieldID = new Guid(Alist[item]),
        FieldValue = objValue[item]
    });
}
```

Comment: i tried this also TaxFieldID = Guid.parse(Alist.Tostring()), this also showing same error

Comment: obviously it is, because `Alist` isn't a Guid. What are you looking for?

Comment: Now i need to pass those six guid's in TaxFieldID and That six fields in fievalue

Comment: Well one way is to use `Guid.Parse()` for each element in the array and then concatinate to a string before assigning.

Comment: if i concatinate means all values save in same column same cell. but i need to save in below format   http://i.stack.imgur.com/42dkd.png

Comment: Amit all are working fine but got one error in End of  the line

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-to-store-array-list-data-into-db-using-asp-net-mvc4 see this link amit

Comment: Amit all are working fine is looping counting is working fine. but when i give  db.TaxInfoTaxField.add(listField) or db..TaxInfoTaxFiled.Add(item) both are showing error..what shall i do . .its showing overload error.

Comment: Should be AddRange() instead

Answer (score 0):

`AList` is an array, not a `Guid`.

You must be doing `Guid.Parse` on entries of `AList`

Something like

```
foreach(string g in AList)
{
     Guid guid = Guid.Parse(g);
     // Guid guid = new Guid(g) also works
}
```